# Regex in python, repeated fragment finding

Tags: python, regex

I try find in text using regex the elements like this: abs=abs , 1=1 etc.
i wrote this i this way:

```
opis="Some text abs=abs sfsdvc"
wyn=re.search('([\w]*)=\1',opis)
print(wyn.group(0))
```

And this find nothing, when i tried this code in the websites like www.regexr.com it was working correctly.
Am I doing something wrong in python re ?

Comment: Why not try something simple like `\w+=\w+`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Because that matches `this=that` too. OP wants the two sides to be equal.

Comment: Ah I see, two similar strings on each side of the =.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid exactly, the text between `(` and `)` will be caught and remembered by the regex engine, then the `\1` will match that caught string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the regex as raw string `r'..'`

```
>>> opis="Some text abs=abs sfsdvc"
>>> wyn=re.search(r'([\w]*)=\1',opis)
>>> print wyn.group(0)
abs=abs
```

[**From re documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)

> Raw string notation (r"text") keeps regular expressions sane. Without it, every backslash ('\') in a regular expression would have to be prefixed with another one to escape it. For example, the two following lines of code are functionally identical:

Meaning, if you are not planing to use raw string, then all the `\` in the string must be escaped as

```
>>> opis="Some text abs=abs sfsdvc"
>>> wyn=re.search('([\\w]*)=\\1',opis)
>>> print wyn.group(0)
abs=abs
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to:

```
re.search(r'(\w+)=\1', opis).group()
          ↑
```

Note that you don't really need character class here, the `[` and `]` are redundant, also it's better to have `\w+` if you don't want to match the string "=" (lonely equal sign).